# Is there a Visual Studios Extension that autofills method variables if matching names exist?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visual-studio-extensions

I was wondering if anyone knew of a Visual Studio Extension that would autofill the parameters passed into a method.  For example, given the following code,

```c#
private void Display(string firstName, string lastName, long phoneNumber)
{
    ...
}

public void Example(long phoneNumber)
{
    string firstName = "John";
    string lastName = "Doe";

    Display()    
}
```

When you type `Display` you could right click on it, and select autofill, and it would check for any local variables with the same exact names, and automaticallly complete the method call for you:

so `Display()` would be converted to `Display(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);` automagically?

Comment: I don't know of any. ReSharper doesn't support this.

Comment: Is there also an extension that does the ironing, makes coffee or gets me an ice cold beer?

Comment: OT: The answer is no, but you could certainly create one? :)

Comment: @mattytommo I'm lazy, what can I say?

Comment: Now that I think of it, if you didn't care about checking if the variable names existed and were correctly typed or not, it wouldn't be too hard to create an extension that did this...

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you'll probably get to this (short of creating your own anyway), **but with a catch**.

Say your `Display` method **didn't exist** and the code for it was inside the `Example` method, like so:

```
public void Example(long phoneNumber)
{
    string firstName = "John";
    string lastName = "Doe";

    //Dummy code to be inside display
    lastName += "pey";
    firstName += "ny";
}
```

Now, highlight everything to go into the `Display` method, right click, choose **Refactor**, then hit **Extract Method**. What that'll do, is give you a dialog where Visual Studio will automatically recognise the parameters needed to build the method signature. Simply add the method name `Display`, click okay on the dialog and **voila**. Your new method is in place and has been replaced with a call to the new method. So you'll end up with:

```
public void Example(long phoneNumber)
{
    string firstName = "John";
    string lastName = "Doe";

    Display(firstName, lastName);
}

public void Display(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    //Dummy code to be inside display
    lastName += "pey";
    firstName += "ny";
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio does this be default in 2010 and beyond.  No ReSharper needed.

Comment: @Daryl Ah really? I've been using ReSharper that long those lines of what does what are *blurred*! Edited to remove the references to ReSharper.

Comment: We've been doing that since VS2005. :-)